# SQL: Max of One Column and Corresponding Other Columns, Joined Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find the max demand for each store for every day and the corresponding hour that the max demand happens in. I have one table with the store number, date and time, and demand value and another tables with the table with the date and time broken out by date and hour.

I need my results to look like this essentially:

```
Max Demand  Date    Hour    Store Number
420 7/1/2019    19  516
415 7/1/2019    20  6228
390 7/1/2019    17  520
402 7/1/2019    20  1363
357 7/1/2019    22  8949
```

I can basically get this without the hour column, but the hour is really important.

This is on Access, so my actual SQL knowlege is very limited. I'm trying use a subquery but I can't figure it out

```
SELECT [Time and Demand].Demand, [Time and Demand].[Store Number], Dates.Hour, Dates.ThisDate
FROM Dates INNER JOIN [Time and Demand] ON Dates.[Date and Time] = [Time and Demand].[Date and Time]

WHERE Demand IN

(SELECT Max([Time and Demand].Demand) AS MaxOfDemand, [Time and Demand].[Store Number], Dates.ThisDate

FROM Dates INNER JOIN [Time and Demand] ON Dates.[Date and Time] = [Time and Demand].[Date and Time])


GROUP BY [Time and Demand].[Store Number], Dates.ThisDate;
```

This gets an error "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's from clause. Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field"

Comment: Remove: `[Time and Demand].[Store Number], Dates.ThisDate` from the select list of the subquery.

Comment: Now it says "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Demand' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: Did you remove them also from the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: You mean at the end in the outer query? I need it grouped by the store number and date at the end

Comment: Now I see that the inner query does not have a GROUP BY clause. I don't know what exactly you want to do, but I will post the code as it should be written so to clear the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This way your subquery will return only 1 column:

```
SELECT td.Demand, td.[Store Number], d.Hour, d.ThisDate
FROM (Dates dINNER JOIN [Time and Demand] td ON d.[Date and Time] = td.[Date and Time])
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(td.Demand) maxdemand, td.[Store Number], d.ThisDate
  FROM Dates d INNER JOIN [Time and Demand] td 
  ON d.[Date and Time] = td.[Date and Time]
  GROUP BY td.[Store Number], d.ThisDate
) g ON g.ThisDate = td.[Date and Time] AND g.[Store Number] = td.[Store Number] AND g.maxdemand = td.Demand
```

Comment: Still gets me the error Your query does not include the specified expression 'Demand' as part of an aggregate function." :/

Comment: It says there's a syntax error (missing operator) in query expression d.[Date and Time] = td.[Date and Time]
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(td.Demand) maxdemand, td.[Store Number], d.ThisDate
  FROM Dates d INNER JOIN [Time and Demand] td 
  ON d.[Date and Time] = td.[Date and Time]
  GROUP BY td.[Store Number], d.ThisDate
) g ON g.ThisDate = td.[Date and Time]